# How do I use nightly builds of Scala 2.9 with maven?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, nightly-build, scala-2.9

Recently I wanted to try some of the new features in Scala 2.9 in a small project. I would like to use maven for building it. How can I tell Maven to use the latest nightly build of Scala 2.9? If someone knows how to do this with sbt instead of maven, that would be good too.

Comment: instructions for Scala 2.11/2.12 and sbt are here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40622878/86485

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this repository:

http://www.scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots

with Scala version: **2.9.0-SNAPSHOT**

Here is snippet for **pom.xml**:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

and for **sbt**:

```
val scalaToolsSnapshots = "Scala Tools Snapshots" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/"
```

Comment: The scala-tools.org site is no longer serving jars.  It appears you can find Scala snapshots at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/scala-lang/