# Slow Compilation when using Scala 2.12.1

Tags: scala, scala-compiler

We recently upgraded from Scala version **2.11.7** to **2.12.1**. After the upgrade we noticed an increase in compilation time of around 10 mins. Reverting back to the old version reduces the compile time for the same code.

Has there been any performance regression introduced as a part of this release ?

Thanks
Shashi

Comment: What fraction of the total compile time is 10 minutes?

Comment: In general, compilation times for 2.11 and 2.12 should be about the same and your experience is not normal. I would suggest you begin by trying a nightly build of 2.12.2 ([instructions here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622878/how-do-i-tell-sbt-to-use-a-nightly-build-of-scala-2-11-or-2-12/40622879#40622879)) to see if the problem has already been fixed.

Comment: @Bob, I would say an increase of around 30%.

Comment: @SethTisue, It seems that there was a performance regression introduced in 2.12.0. https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0-M5 . Can this be the reason for slow compile time ?

Comment: Hey @SethTisue, the instructions for the taking the nightly build talks about SBT. However I am using maven as a build tool. Any idea, how to tweak the maven to get the nightly builds ?

Comment: Surely there must be, but I don't know Maven. That would make a good separate question.

Comment: As for the regression mentioned in the M5 release notes, that was fixed before the final.